# Android "new" statement not working. Loop keeps using the same object

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to create a List of objects in Android (java) from a query in a SQLite database. The code is the following:

```
public List<Aluno> buscaAlunos() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ALUNOS";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
    Aluno aluno = null;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        aluno = new Aluno();//new using same object aways
        aluno.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("ID")));
        aluno.set_nome(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NOME")));
        aluno.set_endereco(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ENDERECO")));
        aluno.set_telefone(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TELEFONE")));
        aluno.set_site(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SITE")));
        aluno.set_nota(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("NOME")));

        alunos.add(aluno);
    }

    c.close();
    return alunos;
}
```

When I try to debug, I get this information on the beginning of the second iteraction(note: I've overwritten Aluno.toString() to show some information in the object):
[first print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxwkW.png)

And then, when I go a few steps in, I can see the same object beeing altered (look at the ArrayList alunos):[second print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBxH4.png)

The result of that code is a list with all the objects in the list having the same value.

Thanks in advance for all the help.
EDIT:
Code for Aluno

```
package com.muffinalunos.muffinmad.muffinalunos.modelo;

public class Aluno {

private static long _ID;
private static String _nome;
private static String _endereco;
private static String _telefone;
private static String _site;
private static float _nota;

public Aluno(){

}

public static long getId() {
    return _ID;
}

public static void setId(long Id) {
    _ID = Id;
}

public static String get_nome() {
    return _nome;
}

public static void set_nome(String _nome) {
    Aluno._nome = _nome;
}

public static String get_endereco() {
    return _endereco;
}

public static void set_endereco(String _endereco) {
    Aluno._endereco = _endereco;
}

public static String get_telefone() {
    return _telefone;
}

public static void set_telefone(String _telefone) {
    Aluno._telefone = _telefone;
}

public static String get_site() {
    return _site;
}

public static void set_site(String _site) {
    Aluno._site = _site;
}

public static float get_nota() {
    return _nota;
}

public static void set_nota(float _nota) {
    Aluno._nota = _nota;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getId()+" - "+get_nome();
}
```

}

Comment: "new using same object aways" Impossible. This would be a violation of the language specification. Please add the code for `Aluno`.

Comment: Let me guess: `static` state in `Aluno`.

Comment: @laalto that's my thought too, hence asking for the code.

Comment: Remove every occurrence of `static` in that class definition.